# ChromeBook Tegra Tk1 runing kernel 4.4.x.x USB Boot with uboot

Tags: chromebook, nvidia-current-dev

UbuntuUsersanDevelops,

I need some tip information about U-boot Board Nyan-Big to runinng Linux v4.4.x.x.

I compiled source 4.4.0.70 Ubuntu distribution in chroot environment in my chormebook Tegra Tk1.
After compilation the generated files were the following:

```
[aperfeito@alarm boot]$ ls -l
total 24992
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 98874 Jul 13 14:54 config-4.4.70-ARCH
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8277506 Jul 13 14:54 initrd.img-4.4.70-ARCH
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2033244 Jul 13 14:54 System.map-4.4.70-ARCH
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15175680 Jul 13 14:54 vmlinuz-4.4.70-ARCH
```

I also compiled the u-boot-tegra in the same environment in chroot Ubuntu Xenial distribution

Make 'nyan-big_defconfig' and everything ok as you see below the generated files:

```
[aperfeito@alarm u-boot-tegra]$ ls *.bin
u-boot.bin u-boot-dtb-tegra.bin u-boot-nodtb-tegra.bin
u-boot-dtb.bin u-boot-nodtb.bin u-boot-tegra.bin
```

Now is the tip I'm asking you:
I have two suggestions on how to put this in the KERNEL partition of my USB.
My USB has two partitions

- To 1st. KERNEL Name with 16 megabytes of space dev / sda6
- A 2st. ROOFS Name approximately 29 Gigabytes of space where I worked
  to compile the UbuntuXenial and Uboot-Tegra srcs kernel as you see:

Sugestion : 1

---

---

```
mkimage -D "-I dts -O dtb -p 2048" -f kernel.its vmlinux.uimg
dd if=/dev/zero of=bootloader.bin bs=512 count=1
vbutil_kernel \
--pack vmlinux.kpart \
--version 1 \
--vmlinuz vmlinux.uimg \
--arch arm \
--keyblock kernel.keyblock \ --> How I do This if necessary
--signprivate kernel_data_key.vbprivk \ --> How I do This if necessary
--config cmdline \ --> TXT file whit this config below
--bootloader bootloader.bin
```

kernel.its adjust to files below as given to te src kernel 4.4.0-70

```
./arch/arm/boot/dts/tegra124-nyan-blaze.dtb
./arch/arm/boot/dts/tegra124-nyan-big.dtb
```

---

TXT CONFIG FILE options

```
console=tty1 init=/sbin/init root=PARTUUID=%U/PARTNROFF=1 rootwait rw noinitrd lsm.module_locking=0
```

### OR

```
initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-ARCH console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty1 ignore_loglevel earlyprintk cgroup_enable=memory root=/dev/sda7
```

#### For config line above need your tip with is the best.

Sugestion: 2

I have to copy the kernel, generated initramfs, and dtb to the SDA6 partition Kernel and added the following kernel config to /dev/sda7/roofsparttion :/boot/extlinux/extlinux.conf below:

```
LABEL UbuntuXenial
MENU LABEL UbuntuXenial on sda7 with 4.4 kernel
LINUX /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0
FDT /boot/dtb/tegra124-nyan-big.dtb
APPEND initrd=/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-ARCH console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty1 ignore_loglevel earlyprintk cgroup_enable=memory root=/dev/sda7
```

How to make U-boot-Tegra now Work with Kernel 4.4.x.x as v3.10.x.x Kernels booting on USB

Best Regards

Perfeito Alexander